# HTML character codes in css

Tags: stylesheet

℀   ℁   ℂ   ℃   ℄   ℅   ℆   ℇ   ℈   ℉   ℊ   ℋ   ℌ   ℍ   ℎ   ℏ   ℐ   ℑ   ℒ   ℓ   ℔   ℕ   №   ℗   ℘   ℙ   ℚ   ℛ   ℜ   ℝ   ℞   ℟
℠   ℡   ™   ℣   ℤ   ℥   Ω   ℧   ℨ   ℩   K   Å   ℬ   ℭ   ℮   ℯ   ℰ   ℱ   Ⅎ   ℳ   ℴ   ℵ   ℶ   ℷ   ℸ   ℹ   ℺   ℻   ℼ   ℽ   ℾ   ℿ
⅀   ⅁   ⅂   ⅃   ⅄   ⅅ   ⅆ   ⅇ   ⅈ   ⅉ   ⅊   ⅋   ⅌   ⅍   ⅎ
⅐   ⅑   ⅒   ⅓   ⅔   ⅕   ⅖   ⅗   ⅘   ⅙   ⅚   ⅛   ⅜   ⅝   ⅞   ⅟
Ⅰ   Ⅱ   Ⅲ   Ⅳ   Ⅴ   Ⅵ   Ⅶ   Ⅷ   Ⅸ   Ⅹ   Ⅺ   Ⅻ   Ⅼ   Ⅽ   Ⅾ   Ⅿ   ⅰ   ⅱ   ⅲ   ⅳ   ⅴ   ⅵ   ⅶ   ⅷ   ⅸ   ⅹ   ⅺ   ⅻ   ⅼ   ⅽ   ⅾ   ⅿ
ↀ   ↁ   ↂ   Ↄ   ↄ   ↅ   ↆ   ↇ   ↈ   ↉   ↊   ↋   ↌   ↍   ↎
←   ↑   →   ↓   ↔   ↕   ↖   ↗   ↘   ↙   ↚   ↛   ↜   ↝   ↞   ↟
↠   ↡   ↢   ↣   ↤   ↥   ↦   ↧   ↨   ↩   ↪   ↫   ↬   ↭   ↮   ↯   ↰   ↱   ↲   ↳   ↴   ↵   ↶   ↷   ↸   ↹   ↺   ↻   ↼   ↽   ↾   ↿
⇀   ⇁   ⇂   ⇃   ⇄   ⇅   ⇆   ⇇   ⇈   ⇉   ⇊   ⇋   ⇌   ⇍   ⇎   ⇏   ⇐   ⇑   ⇒   ⇓   ⇔   ⇕   ⇖   ⇗   ⇘   ⇙   ⇚   ⇛   ⇜   ⇝   ⇞   ⇟
⇠   ⇡   ⇢   ⇣   ⇤   ⇥   ⇦   ⇧   ⇨   ⇩   ⇪   ⇫   ⇬   ⇭   ⇮   ⇯   ⇰   ⇱   ⇲   ⇳   ⇴   ⇵   ⇶   ⇷   ⇸   ⇹   ⇺   ⇻   ⇼   ⇽   ⇾
␀   ␁   ␂   ␃   ␄   ␅   ␆   ␇   ␈   ␉   ␊   ␋   ␌   ␍   ␎   ␏   ␐   ␑   ␒   ␓   ␔   ␕   ␖   ␗   ␘   ␙   ␚   ␛   ␜   ␝   ␞   ␟
␠   ␡   ␢   ␣   ␤   ␥   ␦   ␧   ␨   ␩   ␪   ␫   ␬   ␭   ␮   ␯   ␰   ␱   ␲   ␳   ␴   ␵   ␶   ␷   ␸   ␹   ␺   ␻   ␼   ␽   ␾
─   ━   │   ┃   ┄   ┅   ┆   ┇   ┈   ┉   ┊   ┋   ┌   ┍   ┎   ┏   ┐   ┑   ┒   ┓   └   ┕   ┖   ┗   ┘   ┙   ┚   ┛   ├   ┝   ┞   ┟
┠   ┡   ┢   ┣   ┤   ┥   ┦   ┧   ┨   ┩   ┪   ┫   ┬   ┭   ┮   ┯   ┰   ┱   ┲   ┳   ┴   ┵   ┶   ┷   ┸   ┹   ┺   ┻   ┼   ┽   ┾   ┿
╀   ╁   ╂   ╃   ╄   ╅   ╆   ╇   ╈   ╉   ╊   ╋   ╌   ╍   ╎   ╏   ═   ║   ╒   ╓   ╔   ╕   ╖   ╗   ╘   ╙   ╚   ╛   ╜   ╝   ╞   ╟
╠   ╡   ╢   ╣   ╤   ╥   ╦   ╧   ╨   ╩   ╪   ╫   ╬   ╭   ╮   ╯   ╰   ╱   ╲   ╳   ╴   ╵   ╶   ╷   ╸   ╹   ╺   ╻   ╼   ╽   ╾
▀   ▁   ▂   ▃   ▄   ▅   ▆   ▇   █   ▉   ▊   ▋   ▌   ▍   ▎   ▏   ▐   ░   ▒   ▓   ▔   ▕   ▖   ▗   ▘   ▙   ▚   ▛   ▜   ▝   ▞
■   □   ▢   ▣   ▤   ▥   ▦   ▧   ▨   ▩   ▪   ▫   ▬   ▭   ▮   ▯   ▰   ▱   ▲   △   ▴   ▵   ▶   ▷   ▸   ▹   ►   ▻   ▼   ▽   ▾   ▿
◀   ◁   ◂   ◃   ◄   ◅   ◆   ◇   ◈   ◉   ◊   ○   ◌   ◍   ◎   ●   ◐   ◑   ◒   ◓   ◔   ◕   ◖   ◗   ◘   ◙   ◚   ◛   ◜   ◝   ◞   ◟
◠   ◡   ◢   ◣   ◤   ◥   ◦   ◧   ◨   ◩   ◪   ◫   ◬   ◭   ◮   ◯   ◰   ◱   ◲   ◳   ◴   ◵   ◶   ◷   ◸   ◹   ◺   ◻   ◼   ◽   ◾
☀   ☁   ☂   ☃   ☄   ★   ☆   ☇   ☈   ☉   ☊   ☋   ☌   ☍   ☎   ☏   ☐   ☑   ☒   ☓   ☔   ☕   ☖   ☗   ☘   ☙   ☚   ☛   ☜   ☝   ☞   ☟
☠   ☡   ☢   ☣   ☤   ☥   ☦   ☧   ☨   ☩   ☪   ☫   ☬   ☭   ☮   ☯   ☰   ☱   ☲   ☳   ☴   ☵   ☶   ☷   ☸   ☹   ☺   ☻   ☼   ☽   ☾   ☿
♀   ♁   ♂   ♃   ♄   ♅   ♆   ♇   ♈   ♉   ♊   ♋   ♌   ♍   ♎   ♏   ♐   ♑   ♒   ♓   ♔   ♕   ♖   ♗   ♘   ♙   ♚   ♛   ♜   ♝   ♞   ♟
♠   ♡   ♢   ♣   ♤   ♥   ♦   ♧   ♨   ♩   ♪   ♫   ♬   ♭   ♮   ♯   ♰   ♱   ♲   ♳   ♴   ♵   ♶   ♷   ♸   ♹   ♺   ♻   ♼   ♽   ♾   ♿
⚀   ⚁   ⚂   ⚃   ⚄   ⚅   ⚆   ⚇   ⚈   ⚉   ⚊   ⚋   ⚌   ⚍   ⚎   ⚏   ⚐   ⚑   ⚒   ⚓   ⚔   ⚕   ⚖   ⚗   ⚘   ⚙   ⚚   ⚛   ⚜   ⚝   ⚞   ⚟
⚠   ⚡   ⚢   ⚣   ⚤   ⚥   ⚦   ⚧   ⚨   ⚩   ⚪   ⚫   ⚬   ⚭   ⚮   ⚯   ⚰   ⚱   ⚲   ⚳   ⚴   ⚵   ⚶   ⚷   ⚸   ⚹   ⚺   ⚻   ⚼   ⚽   ⚾   ⚿
⛀   ⛁   ⛂   ⛃   ⛄   ⛅   ⛆   ⛇   ⛈   ⛉   ⛊   ⛋   ⛌   ⛍   ⛎   ⛏   ⛐   ⛑   ⛒   ⛓   ⛔   ⛕   ⛖   ⛗   ⛘   ⛙   ⛚   ⛛   ⛜   ⛝   ⛞   ⛟
⛠   ⛡   ⛢   ⛣   ⛤   ⛥   ⛦   ⛧   ⛨   ⛩   ⛪   ⛫   ⛬   ⛭   ⛮   ⛯   ⛰   ⛱   ⛲   ⛳   ⛴   ⛵   ⛶   ⛷   ⛸   ⛹   ⛺   ⛻   ⛼   ⛽   ⛾
✀   ✁   ✂   ✃   ✄   ✅   ✆   ✇   ✈   ✉   ✊   ✋   ✌   ✍   ✎   ✏   ✐   ✑   ✒   ✓   ✔   ✕   ✖   ✗   ✘   ✙   ✚   ✛   ✜   ✝   ✞   ✟
✠   ✡   ✢   ✣   ✤   ✥   ✦   ✧   ✨   ✩   ✪   ✫   ✬   ✭   ✮   ✯   ✰   ✱   ✲   ✳   ✴   ✵   ✶   ✷   ✸   ✹   ✺   ✻   ✼   ✽   ✾   ✿
❀   ❁   ❂   ❃   ❄   ❅   ❆   ❇   ❈   ❉   ❊   ❋   ❌   ❍   ❎   ❏   ❐   ❑   ❒   ❓   ❔   ❕   ❖   ❗   ❘   ❙   ❚   ❛   ❜   ❝   ❞   ❟
❠   ❡   ❢   ❣   ❤   ❥   ❦   ❧   ❨   ❩   ❪   ❫   ❬   ❭   ❮   ❯   ❰   ❱   ❲   ❳   ❴   ❵   ❶   ❷   ❸   ❹   ❺   ❻   ❼   ❽   ❾   ❿
➀   ➁   ➂   ➃   ➄   ➅   ➆   ➇   ➈   ➉   ➊   ➋   ➌   ➍   ➎   ➏   ➐   ➑   ➒   ➓   ➔   ➕   ➖   ➗   ➘   ➙   ➚   ➛   ➜   ➝   ➞   ➟
➠   ➡   ➢   ➣   ➤   ➥   ➦   ➧   ➨   ➩   ➪   ➫   ➬   ➭   ➮   ➯   ➰   ➱   ➲   ➳   ➴   ➵   ➶   ➷   ➸   ➹   ➺   ➻   ➼   ➽   ➾
⟀   ⟁   ⟂   ⟃   ⟄   ⟅   ⟆   ⟇   ⟈   ⟉   ⟊   ⟋   ⟌   ⟍   ⟎   ⟏   ⟐   ⟑   ⟒   ⟓   ⟔   ⟕   ⟖   ⟗   ⟘   ⟙   ⟚   ⟛   ⟜   ⟝   ⟞   ⟟
⟠   ⟡   ⟢   ⟣   ⟤   ⟥   ⟦   ⟧   ⟨   ⟩   ⟪   ⟫   ⟬   ⟭   ⟮
⟰   ⟱   ⟲   ⟳   ⟴   ⟵   ⟶   ⟷   ⟸   ⟹   ⟺   ⟻   ⟼   ⟽   ⟾

Is it safe to use these characters as this article suggests http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/03/19/styling-elements-with-glyphs-sprites-and-pseudo-elements/

Will all the chars be displayed to all users I ran a browser shot test http://browsershots.org/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8368699/html-character-codes-in-css

But will my users be able to see all

Comment: Safe in what sense? they don't all render on MY screen, if that's what you mean.

Comment: Please put the question in the beginning of the text, so that it is shown on the summary page. Now there's only a block of strange characters showing up in the question summary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, yes, though I'm not sure if all systems/browsers/fonts have all of them. I, for instance, see quite a few placeholder rectangles here.

Comment: so are there any safe set that i can use

Comment: I'd say you can rely on the minimum subset of discernable characters in the browsershots.